# How to search for elements in other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes(df1 and df2). df1 is comprised of basketball players and df2 is comprised of famous athletes from varying sports. I am trying to create a function that will search if the name of the basketball player in df1 is in df2, if true append it to a matched column and add string x to the description column, if false append nan. How do I do that?

```
x = 'basketball player'
```

df1
| Player | Team | Matched | Description |
| ------ | ---- | ------- | ----------- |
| Michael Jordan | Chicago Bulls |  |  |
| Kobe Bryant | Los Angeles Lakers |  |  |
| Lebron James | Los Angeles Lakers |  |  |

df2
| Player | Sport | Position |
| ------ | ----- | -------- |
| Deion Sanders | Football | DB |
| Michael Jordan | Basketball | SG |
| Barry Sanders | Football | RB |
| Kobe Bryant | Basketball | SG |

expected outcome df1
| Player | Team | Matched | Description |
| ------ | ---- | ------- | ----------- |
| Michael Jordan| Chicago Bulls| Michael Jordan| basketball player|
| Kobe Bryant| Los Angeles Lakers| Kobe Bryant| basketball player|
| Lebron James| Los Angeles Lakers| nan| nan|

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: If you are sure df1 is all basketball players, you could do `df1.merge(df2.loc[df2.Sport=='Basketball'], on='Player')`

Comment: How would I go about adding the description if indicator = true ?